# Convert json to arraylist to String[] in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, arrays, json

I have looked at several discussions on this topics but no conclusive answer has been given. I have an issue, am trying to get data from MySql database into JSON and into Array List, then finally into a String[] which will populate the ListView.

Am trying to Convert an ArrayList to a String[] Array
 `myDataLists` Contains all the values picked up from JSON, and dataList is the String Array to populate the `ListView` using the `LazerAdapter`.

The Conversion is as follows

```
String[] dataList = new String[myDataLists.size()];
        dataList = myDataLists.toArray(dataList);
```

I have tried this and it works properly

```
String dataList[] = {"Value 1","Value 2", "Value 3"}
```

However i want the values to come from the db and so I have narrowed down to the problem. Its the `String[] Array`, it picks the values but may not be registered as a String Array and so it gives a blank String[] Array;

The following is my scenario.

The List Loading

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LoadRecentData().execute();

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, dataList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What would be the proper way to get the Correct String[] Array that will output

`{"Value 1","Value 2", "Value 3"}`

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: what's in myDataLists ?

Comment: myDataLists contains all values from JSON

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a `stringarray` from an `arrayList` ?

use `String [] dataList = (String[]) myDataLists.toArray(new String[0]);`

Read [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) here